# Remove line breaks from images with a hyperlink without using table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` containing images as

```
<div>
   <img src="pic1.jpg" />
   <img src="pic2.jpg" />
   <img src="pic3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Now whenever I put a hyperlink over any of the images, it causes a line - break.

I have tried  adding `display:block; display:inline; float: left`to the images. But the line break still occurs.

Using  a `<table>` is not an option in this case . How do I fix the line - break without using a `<table>`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7seS9/). I took your HTML, wrapped a hyperlink around each image, and they're still positioned horizontally next to each other. Chrome, Win7x64.

Comment: Images are `inline-block` elements which means they flow next to each other assuming your parent div has enough width. Links are `inline` elements. This means by default they should not line break like blocks do. Make sure your parent container is wide enough to fit all 3 images, keep in mind any padding you added. Make sure there isn't a global setting where  you changed `<a>` tags to blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `float: left; clear: none;`